# Integrating Manual Date Entry in Bulma Calendar with React Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, bulma

I'm working on a React project where I use the Bulma Calendar component. My goal is to enable manual date entry, a feature not present in the standard version. I found a promising fork by [meta-system-GmbH on GitHub (meta-system-GmbH/bulma-calendar)](https://github.com/meta-system-GmbH/bulma-calendar/commit/2fbcbde218e1b4065d89b52e33e38a00a1780f53), which appears to add this functionality. However, despite following the configuration instructions in the README and setting the editTimeManually flag to true, the input field remains read-only, and I'm unable to manually enter dates.

Has anyone successfully implemented this fork in a React project with working manual date entry? I am looking for examples, demonstrations, or advice on implementing this specific functionality. Any guidance, including code snippets or similar project references, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

- I tried using a fork of Bulma Calendar by meta-system-GmbH, which supposedly adds manual date entry functionality.
- I followed the README instructions for setup and specifically set the `editTimeManually` flag to `true` in your project configuration.
- Despite this setup, the input field remained read-only, contrary to expectations. I was expecting the input field to allow manual typing of dates after these adjustments.